# Gitignore everything except a dir with its subfiles

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to exclude all files except a single directory, I have seen other solutions but none works:

```
!home/
home/*
!home/.bashrc

home/some_dir/*
!home/some_dir/src/

home/some_dir/src/*
!home/some_dir/src/some_other_dir/
```

Git can see `.bashrc` and `.gitignore` but not the `some_other_dir`.

Comment: Hi, no. I tried it and updated my question.

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6754986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

```
!home/
home/*

!home/some_dir
home/some_dir/*

!home/some_dir/src
home/some_dir/src/*

!home/some_dir/src/some_other_dir

!home/.bashrc
```